# Как установить Windows 10 на внешний диск с загрузчиком rEFInd?

Tags: windows-10, ssd, uefi

товарищи, смотрите, такая проблема:

Взял себе внешний SSD и хочу туда поставить Windows 10. Но установщик отказывается ставить на "подключенные по USB или IEEE диски". Мне нужна именно Windows 10 (в т ч ради загрузки посредством UEFI, а не MBR/Legacy Boot), не 8ка и не 11. (оборудование - нормальный ПК с UEFI, так что 7ка там вообще не факт, что заведется адекватно, хотя тут я не уверен. Да и она тоже не нужна, под неё - больно старые версии ПО). Есть идея с виртуальным диском и плагином vhdboot, но все это вроде бы под 7ку, я не знаю, есть ли такое под десятку, плюс мне надо сразу на loop-image.vhd поставить, без использования виртуалки (в т ч чтобы не было проблем с драйверами). Есть вариант с Ventoy + root.img, где все уже сделано "под капотом", но тут та же проблема, что и с vhdboot + а не будет ли проблем с готовой системой (а не install.iso) при таком раскладе? А во2, и самое главное, мне надо грузить систему не bootmgr.efi, а refind.efi (причина: multiboot support), а вот как это все прикрутить друг к другу - неясно...

Вариант "поставить Windows куда-то ещё и выкатить раздел через dd" (я так один раз восстанавливал Windows после повреждения таблицы разделов) не прокатит, ибо Windows ставить больше некуда, а перебивать пк я не хочу...

Comment: Мы использовали Windows To Go - делается очень просто. НО, ЕМНИП, это работает или с корпоративкой или с академической. Поскольку у нас и то, и то, я затрудняюсь ответить, какая версия из этих двух нужна.

Comment: у меня Windows 10 Pro и Windows 10 Home.

Comment: Нет, я уточнил, это сработает только с корпоративной или академической версией. Так что для обычных версий - отпадает, но пригодится тем, у кого вышеуказанные версии. Подозреваю, в вашем случае остается лишь вариант: поставить Windows на HDD/SDD, а затем перенести образ на носитель.